# how to optimize react app for real time Data streaming

Tags: javascript, reactjs, socket.io, react-hooks

I am working on a project which involves real-time data streaming from node js servers to react js. This data is further used to display real-time charts. I am using socket io for real-time data stream .my code for the app

```
const socket = io.connect("http://localhost:4000")
function App() {
const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false)

const [count, setCount] = useState(0)

const [GD, setGD] = useState([])
const dataGather = (data1) => {
var len = GD.length;

if (len >50) {
  var array = GD; // make a separate copy of the array
  console.log(len)
  var index = array.indexOf(len);
    array.splice(index, 1);
    setGD(array);
  
} else {
  setGD(GD => [data1, ...GD])
}

}

useEffect(() => {
socket.on("connect", () => {
  console.log("connected Successfully");
});

socket.on('wave', (data1) => {


  //i  want to run this part only one time so i used count here
  if (count < 1) {
    setCount(1)
   
    setShowModal(true);
  }
  dataGather(data1);
})
},[]);
return (
<div className="App">

  <Iframe iframe={demos["htmlPage"]} allow="autoplay" className="ifr1" sandbox="allow-scripts" />


  {showModal == true ? <Example hideModal={hideModal} GD={GD} showModal={showModal} /> : <></>}
</div>
);
```

In this code, I want to display when new data arrives I call a function which helps to open MODAL BOX.inside Modal my graph component is called and display the graph.
key problems:

1. Datastream is so fast
2. when I open the modal the other back UI
   stops working.
3. when I close the Modal data takes time to stop.
4. I also want to empty my last index of the array every time so that every new entry is appended at the start.

My Modal Component

```
useEffect(() => {
handleChannelId();
}, [GD])
return (
<>

  {
    ch > 0 ?
      <Modal size="lg" aria-labelledby="contained-modal-title-vcenter" backdrop="static" keyboard={false} centered show={show} onHide={handleClose}  >
        <Modal.Header closeButton className=" text-dark py-1 header-bg bg-light">
          <Modal.Title>Channel ID: {ch}</Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>

        <Modal.Body className="p-0" style={{ backgroundColor: "#062F2E" }}>
          <Row>
            <Col lg={11} className="p-2">
              <div id="zoom-graph" style={{ backgroundColor: "black", width: "730px", height: "400px", border: "1px solid white" }}>
                <Graph GD={GD} zoom={zoom} /></div>
            </Col><Col lg={1} style={{ padding: "30px" }}>
              <input className="pl-3" type="range" value={zoom} class="form-range" orient="vertical" onChange={(e)=>setZoom(e.target.value)} min={-250} max={250} step={50} id="customRange3"></input>
            

            </Col>
          </Row>
        </Modal.Body>
      </Modal>
      : <></>}
</>
);
}
```

Comment: Is there an issue with the code? If you're looking for a code review for refining working code then [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is more on-topic for this question.

Comment: no there is no issue with code. Actually i want to optimize and speed up my app.

Comment: As a general question that's pretty off-topic on SO. If you were *attempting* to optimize or "speed up" a very specific aspect, and were having issues, something not working as expected, etc.. this would be more on topic as something we could "address and fix". It's just too broad at this point.